# XAML button comand to pass to date picker properties to method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am quite new to XMAL but have managed to cobble together a form that retrieves data from SQL and populates a data grid. To extend this I want to only return data based on two dates. I have created a method GetAllActionLogsBetweenDates() this takes two properties QueryFromDate, QueryToDate.

I need to pass the 2 dates from the date pickers to the GetAllActionLogsBetweenDates method when the FindButton is clicked.

My XAML looks like this

```
<StackPanel Height="114" 
                    Orientation="Vertical"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Name="StackPanel1" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Width="507">
            <DatePicker Height="25"
                        SelectedDate="{Binding QueryFromDate, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Width="115"
                        x:Name="DateFrom"
                        Margin="5"/>
            <DatePicker Height="25"
                        SelectedDate="{Binding QueryToDate, Mode=TwoWay}"                        
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                        Width="115"
                        Margin ="5 "
                        x:Name="DateTo"/>
            <Button Content="Find"
                    x:Name="FindButton"
                    Command="{Binding ?????}"
                    Height="23" 
                    Margin="5"
                    Width="75" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
        </StackPanel>
```

I think I have to do something in the Command="{Binding ?????}" element referencing my method and presumably the 2 properties QueryFromDate, QueryToDate but I am not sure what

Thanks

Comment: If your bindings are working, your dates should already be in QueryFromDate and QueryToDate. If you're using MVVM and a ViewModel file (instead of the codebehind), it can sometimes be easier to use an MVVM framework that implements ICommand for you. Otherwise, you could just use the `Click=""` event on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using MVVM, you first need to define the `RelayCommand` object that implements `ICommand` like so:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Predicate<object> m_canExecute;
    private Action<object> m_execute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        m_execute = execute;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Predicate<object> canExecute, Action<object> execute)
    {
        m_canExecute = CanExecute;
        m_execute = execute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (m_canExecute == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return m_canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (m_execute != null)
        {
            m_execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

You then need to create a command for your button in the ViewModel. Something like this:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    public ICommand GetAllActionLogsBetweenDatesCommand { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        GetAllActionLogsBetweenDatesCommand = new RelayCommand(GetAllActionLogsBetweenDates_Execute);
    }

    private void GetAllActionLogsBetweenDates_Execute(object parameter)
    {
        try
        {
            var stringList = parameter as string[];

            DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Parse(stringList[0]);
            DateTime toDate = DateTime.Parse(stringList[1]);
            // Query the data.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Now since you want to pass **multiple** parameters to the command, you can use an `IMultiValueConverter` to get the two dates selected and pass them to the ViewModel. This is how the converter would look like:

```
public class ICommandMultiDateConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new string[] { values[0].ToString(), values[1].ToString() };
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And finally, in your XAML you create an instance of this converter and bind it to your button:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <myNamespace:ICommandMultiDateConverter x:Key="multiDateConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<DatePicker Name="fromDatePicker"></DatePicker>
<DatePicker Name="toDatePicker"></DatePicker>
<Button Content="Hello World">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=multiDateConverter}">
            <Binding ElementName="fromDatePicker" Path="Text"></Binding>
            <Binding ElementName="toDatePicker" Path="Text"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
    <Button.Command>
        <Binding Path="GetAllActionLogsBetweenDatesCommand"></Binding>
    </Button.Command>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a ViewModel, you'll need to implement `ICommand` and create a Command in your ViewModel class.

This question has an example implementation you could use: [How to bind WPF button to a command in ViewModelBase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422945/how-to-bind-wpf-button-to-a-command-in-viewmodelbase)

Alternatively, if you're just using your codebehind (.xaml.cs), you can use the [`Click`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click(v=vs.110).aspx) event:

```
<Button Content="Find" Click="FindClicked" />
```

You'd then add the `FindClicked` method into your codebehind:

```
void FindClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { }
```