# XAML outsourcing datatemplate with events in APP.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling, windows-phone-8.1

I'm having a working datatemplate for a `ListView` with `ItemTemplate`

```
<ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MYTEMPLATE}"             
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
          ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.IsEntranceElement="True">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

The Template looks like that:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GlobalBox">
        <Border Background="#FFFFFFFF" Margin="10 0 0 5" CornerRadius="2 2 15 2">
            <Grid Width="380">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Tag="{Binding ID}" Name="ProfileInfo" Tapped="Profile_Tapped" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15 15 15 0">
                    <Grid Width="360" Margin="0 0 0 10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0" Height="45" Width="45" CornerRadius="5">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0 5 0 0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Handle}" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="12"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="Assets/ActionIcons/logo_blue_32.png" Width="32" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Image>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel  Grid.Row="1" Margin="14.5,0,0,0" Height="Auto">
                    <StackPanel Name="TweetContent" Tag="{Binding ID}" Margin="15 0 15 0" Tapped="Content_Tapped">
                        <TextBlock Text ="{Binding Content}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14" Margin="0 0 0 10"/>
                        <ItemsControl  ItemsSource="{Binding ContentImages}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="{Binding }" MaxWidth="350" Margin="0 0 0 5"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Image>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="DarkGray" Text="{Binding DateSend}" FontSize="10"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Name="ActionButtons">
                        <Grid Tag="{Binding ID}" Width="380" Height="25" Margin="0 0 0 10">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Button Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20 0 0 0" Style="{StaticResource replyActionButton}" Tapped="Reply_Tapped"></Button>

                            <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                          Style="{StaticResource retweetActionButton}" 
                                          Tapped="Retweet_Tapped"></ToggleButton>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-15 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding RetweetCount}" Foreground="DarkGray"/>

                            <ToggleButton Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                          Style="{StaticResource likeActionButton}" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding LikeState}"  
                                          Tapped="Favourite_Tapped"></ToggleButton>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="5"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-15 0 0 0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding LikeCount}" Foreground="DarkGray"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And now when I put the template in the app.xaml file I am getting the following compile error

*Events cannot be set in the Application class XAML file*

This makes sense for me, but how can I do it anyway? Can I pass the different events like a variable or something into the datatemplate?

//UPDATE - SOLUTION WAY2 using the USERCONTROL:

I've made a UserControl out of the code above and implemented it in the ListView.

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 0 0 5"       
        x:Name = "standardBox"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.IsEntranceElement="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:UCGlobal></local:UCGlobal>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a few alternatives:

1. Use the command property of the buttons inside your templates (take care that your `DataContext` is set correct, to avoid binding errors):

   ```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
       <StackPanel>
           <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button1" Command="{Binding Btn1Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=button1}"/>
           <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button2" Command="{Binding Btn2Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=button2}"/>
           <Button x:Name="button3" Content="Button3" Command="{Binding Btn3Command}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=button3}"/>
       </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

If it´s another type of event that won't call the command you could use `InvokeCommandAction` which will be handled same as shown in the next example.

2. Use a trigger like `CallMethodAction` (same as above. The `DataContext` is the place where the method will be searched for.):

   ```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
       <StackPanel>
           <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button1" >
               <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                   <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tapped">
                       <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="button1_Tapped"/>
                   </i:EventTrigger>
               </i:Interaction.Triggers>
           </Button>...
   ```
3. Write a small `UserControl` as the base for your `DataTemplate`:

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="ThreeBtnUserCtrl"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataTemplateIssue"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
       <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" Click="button1_Click"/>
       <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Button" Click="button2_Click"/>
       <Button x:Name="button3" Content="Button" Click="button3_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class ThreeBtnUserCtrl : UserControl
{
    public ThreeBtnUserCtrl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //...some code only controlling view related stuff of your UserCtrl
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //...some code only controlling view related stuff of your UserCtrl
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //...some code only controlling view related stuff of your UserCtrl
    }
}
```

Use it inside your `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <local:ThreeBtnUserCtrl/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Ok, Thx. I tried alternative 1 without success so far. I'll changed the template as you described it. But now I'm not sure how to fill the `Command` and `CpmmandParameters` in the `ListView`. I've tried the following:
        <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"
                >
            
            <Button x:Name="Button1" Command="Like_Tapped" CommandParameter="Tapped"></Button>
            <Button x:Name="Button2" Command="Dislike_Tapped" CommandParameter="Tapped"></Button>
</ListView>

Comment: Command="{Binding ElementName=ListviewName,Path=DataContext. Btn1Command}", Assuming Btn1Command is in Listview's datacontext.

Comment: Sorry guys, I think made a mistake explaining my problem. I tried to explain as easy as possible and have shortened my code by a lot.
The event handlers are not set to a `Button ` they are set to various `StackPanels`. And now I cant use the `Command ` property @Archana has posted.

Comment: @Archana Updated my question.
The Tap Events to replace are:
`Profile_Tapped`, `Content_Tapped`, `Reply_Tapped`, `Favourite_Tapped`, `Retweet_Tapped`

Comment: You still can use this Command="{Binding ElementName=ListviewName,Path=DataContext. Btn1Command}",what exception you are getting?

Comment: Is it Windows phone 8.1?

Comment: @Archana Yes WP8.1
There is no command property available for `Stackpanel` or `ListView`

Comment: You can use behaviours   <interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped" >
                    <interactcore:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.Btn1Command}" />
                </interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interact:Interaction.Behaviors>

Comment: Use these namespaces  xmlns:interact="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" 
    xmlns:interactcore="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"

Comment: I have added my answer,check it. Please edit the tag to WIndows phone 8.1  also.

Comment: @Archana I've added the two namespaces in both XAML files. Then I've added your behavior to the StackPanel in the APP.XAML but the behaviours won't get found in the namspace...

Comment: You have to add Behavioural SDK reference. Go to add reference->Extensions->Behavioural SDK

Comment: @Archana Ok. reference is working. Will need a few moments to do the rest. looks good so far,

Comment: @Archana Is it right that I have to implement the ICommand interface in my class which I want to bind like it is described [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422945/how-to-bind-wpf-button-to-a-command-in-viewmodelbase).
Still struggeling with the `Command="{Binding DataContext.Btn1Command}'`

Comment: If you use prism framework it's easy. No need to implement ICommand

Comment: Easiest way is as mentioned in above answer use UserControl approach

Comment: @Archana Thank You very much. I decided to implement the UserControl. 
I'll update my Question so future reader will know. 
I'm now having some trouble retrieving the sender variable in the eventhandler function. If you know what this error is about let me know, but I think it is time to close this post and open eventually a new one.
Thanks again for beeing so patient with me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Command` and `EventTrigger` and have it bound to your View Model’s command.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tapped">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TappedCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Or use a small `UserControl` insted a `DataTemplate`:

```
<UserControl... >
    <StackPanel>
       <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Button" Click="button1_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And use it in your app.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Template">
    <Grid>
        <local:myUserControl/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Behaviours in stackpanel

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GlobalBox">
    <Border Background="#FFFFFFFF" Margin="10 0 0 5" CornerRadius="2 2 15 2">
        <Grid Width="380">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Tag="{Binding ID}" Name="ProfileInfo" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="15 15 15 0">
                <Grid Width="360" Margin="0 0 0 10">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="75"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0" Height="45" Width="45" CornerRadius="5">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0 5 0 0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Handle}" Foreground="DarkGray" FontSize="12"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Image Grid.Column="2" Source="Assets/ActionIcons/logo_blue_32.png" Width="32" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Image>
                </Grid>
                <interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped" >
                        <interactcore:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.Btn1Command}" />
                    </interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior>
                </interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: This worked but caused me more additional work in the code-behind than using the Usercontrol so I've went the other way. Thanks!