# WPF: ICommand Bindings not working with Pages

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

`tl;dr`: Changed `Window`s to two `Pages` and a `NavigationWindow`, `ICommand Bindings` stopped working.

So I copied the `Grid` from my `MainWindow` to a fresh `MainPage`, setup the `NavigationWindow` and so on. All is set, build without error, even the Binding for `Strings` and others are working. What does not work, are the `ICommand` Bindings for my `Buttons`. But they did work before.

Example `ICommand`:

```
class ComPortChosen : ICommand
{
    private MainViewModel mainVm;
    public ComPortChosen(MainViewModel mainVm)
    {
        this.mainVm = mainVm;
    }
    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
            return true;
    }

    event EventHandler ICommand.CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //set a breakpoint here, method was **not** entered
        int i = 1337;
    }
}
```

In the `MainViewModel.class`:

```
public ICommand chooseComPort { get; set; }
private MainPage mainPage;

public MainViewModel(MainView view)
{
    chooseComPort = new ComPortChosen(this);

    mainPage = new MainPage(this);
}
```

In my `MainPage.xaml`:

```
 <Button 
     x:Name="btn_choose" 
     Content="Choose" Grid.Column="10" Grid.Row="2" 
     Command="{Binding chooseComPort}" Margin="0,49,0,0"/>
```

Since the other `Bindings` (strings, bool, custom converter) do work, I assume that I set up the `DataContext` correctly.

Comment: have you tried using a program such as snoop to find what the datacontext is set to at runtime? You could also put a break point in the Constructor to see what the datacontext is when the new page is loaded

Comment: `DataContext` is the set `MainViewModel`, since I set it in the constructor. :/
I haven't worked with such a program..

Comment: What does `Output` window says when you click at the Button? To see `Output` Window run your program by `F5`.

Comment: In addition, try to write like this: `Command="{Binding DataContext.chooseComPort}"`. What is `this` inside of `chooseComPort = new ComPortChosen(this);`. Instead of this you should write a method which will be invoked when button is clicked.

Comment: There is nothing in the `Output` when I press the `Button`. @StepUp.
I have tried to add the `DataContext` like that, unfortunately, it did not work.

`this` in the constructor is the `MainViewModel` instance. The method, which will be executed is in the `ComPortChosen.class` (`void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)`).

Comment: How to debug binding errors http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/debugging/
What you should write instead of `this` in `Command` handler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422945/how-to-bind-wpf-button-to-a-command-in-viewmodelbase

Comment: Debug with `Command="{Binding chooseComPort, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"`seems fine, no errors or suspicious lines. Passing the method to the `Command`/making the `Command handler` a property handler solved my problem. Thank you.