# Change xaml properties with commands

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

I want to open and close the splitview.pane with commands. This is my sample xaml-code:

```
<SplitView Name="AppNavigation" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False" CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="200">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <Button Name="Hamburger" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" FontSize="24" Width="50" Height="50" Command="{Binding HamburgerExecute}" />
    </SplitView.Pane>
</SplitView>
```

I use a RelayCommand class and call these two methods:

```
    private bool HamburgerCanExecute(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void HamburgerExecute(object obj)
    {
        AppNavigation.IsPaneOpen = !AppNavigation.IsPaneOpen; // this doesn't work
    }
```

Can someone explain to me how I use commands to change xaml properties?

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code? Is the program entering your command? As you are using binding - have you set the datacontext?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind WPF button to a command in ViewModelBase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422945/how-to-bind-wpf-button-to-a-command-in-viewmodelbase) Not entirely the duplicate but boils down to the same problem. (How to bind commands)

Comment: You say you use a `RelayCommand` class which, I assume, implements `ICommand`. Do you bind to this command ? It looks like you bind to a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to integrate UI namespaces ... damn

So the correct code is:

```
private void HamburgerExecute(object obj)
{
    SplitView navigation = obj as SplitView;
    navigation.IsPaneOpen = !navigation.IsPaneOpen;
}
```

And CommandParameter in my xaml file:

```
<SplitView Name="AppNavigation" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False" CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="200">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <Button Name="Hamburger" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" FontSize="24" Width="50" Height="50" Command="{Binding HamburgerCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AppNavigation}" />
    </SplitView.Pane>
</SplitView>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're directly binding the method to your `Button`, but you stated that you are using `RelayCommand`. Please make sure that you're binding the `RelayCommand` and not the actual method.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks that was still a mistake, but how can I now manipulate IsPaneOpen? AppNavigation is not known in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Create a click-event in your button.

```
<SplitView Name="AppNavigation" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False" CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="200">
<SplitView.Pane>
    <Button Name="Hamburger" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" FontSize="24" Width="50" Height="50" Click="Hamburger_Click />
</SplitView.Pane>
```

C#:

```
private void Hamburger_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AppNavigation.IsPaneOpen = !AppNavigation.IsPaneOpen;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to use commands and mvvm pattern. A click-event in the code-behind ist therefore not an option for me.